# I need a good mouse to replace my Microsoft Intellimouse 3.0

Tags: mice

I used to have a wonderful Microsoft Intellimouse 3.0 - it had excellent button layout, size, and AFAIK a great sensor on it. Unfortunately I think the right click button has worn out, so I'll need to replace it (if you think it can be repaired let me know that *along* with your replacement suggestion).

What I want in a mouse:

- laser/optical
- two thumb buttons (forward/backward ideally)
- medium size
- smooth scrolling a plus
- sensor polling and sensitivity relatively high
- USB wired
- DPI switch button a plus
- no glued on "grips"
- if lit, white, green, or configurable lights are preferred
- scanner mouse would be neat - can it still be a good gaming mouse?
- easy to clean underside
- ideally less than $40

Comment: I am flexible, so don't be afraid to make a suggestion even if most of the requirements aren't met, so long as you think I might be satisfied. As in the pirate's code, these are more like *guidelines*

Comment: I personally wouldn't trust a scanner mouse with gaming just because it isn't a regular mouse. I feel like the extra scanning feature would cause problems.

Comment: @Adam yes, I would ideally like to see reviews or some other kind of evidence to the effect that the scanner doesn't interfere with performance. However, I have some faith that the two tasks are not mutually exclusive for me, because I don't need perfection in either category (I'm willing to compromise), and mechanically there is nothing really different between a scanner and an optical mouse's tracking camera. Indeed, there are reports of DIYers hacking old optical mice to create their own scanners. I am pinning my hopes on that theoretical equality of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury meets most of the requirements. It is a little more than your ideal price. It is $49.99 on newegg http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=g402&N=-1&isNodeId=1

- It is a wired laser/optical mouse
- The resolution is from 240 to 4000 DPI at 1000hz data polling
- It has three configurable thumb buttons and two other macro buttons. Any of which can be configured as a DPS button
- It has a blue light, but it is configurable if you want to adjust it or turn it off.
- It has solid construction

--

- It is a larger mouse
- It is not a scanner mouse
- It does not have smooth scrolling